# What do you mean by optimal and suboptimal routes in network topologies?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I was reading about "hub and spoke" topology and "full-mesh" topology and i came across the terms optimal and suboptimal routes, what does these terms exactly means?
Why are optimal routes necessary in "hub and spoke topology"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **optimal** (ˈɒptɪm(ə)) *adjective*
>   best or most favourable; optimum.
>   "seeking the optimal solution"

The optimal route will be the fastest or most efficient route, and therefore would be the preferred route over which to transfer data.

Sub-optimal routes will be slower and therefore not the preferred route.

If you are not using an optimal route then you are wasting time and bandwidth.

Simple spoke-type networks are sub optimal because you always have to go to the centre point of the hub and then out to the machine you need rather than being able to go directly to whichever node you need. The hub becomes a bottleneck in the network as all data must go through it. With a more scattered network using multiple hubs and switches a less congested route (i.e. more optimal) could be found between machines

Comment: Got it.
But it is said that hub-and-spoke technology uses suboptimal routes, any comments on that?

Comment: They are sub optimal because you *always* have to go to the centre point of the hub and then out to the machine you need rather than being able to go directly to whichever node you need. The hub becomes a bottleneck in the network as all data must go through it. With a more scattered network using multiple hubs and switches a less congested route (i.e. more optimal) could be found between machines.